# Names of geographic features on moons or planets other than Earth found later to be controversial or provocative? Have any then been changed?

Tags: history, place-names

The names of places and geographic features (and even buildings) on Earth is an interesting topic; sometimes they are later changed after concerns are raised. And of course there is the deliberate gamesmanship of changing the names of sections of streets where another country's embassy sits to make their mailing address awkward or unappealing to the embassy's country.

But this question is strictly about *off-world names.*

**Question:** Have there been any names of geographic features on moons or planets other than Earth that were ever later found to be controversial or provocative? Have any of them ever been subsequently changed?

Comment: Astronomy stack?

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's a toss-up but honestly I think that folks there are going to be less aware of the history of naming craters from photos taken by NASA spacecraft, which seems to be the bulk of the names from which answers here will come from.

Comment: @OrganicMarble let's give it a few weeks or so here, and if nothing pops up I'll reconsider moving it there or ask to have it migrated. If the question were about naming asteroids, things that would be in the minor planet data center, or exoplanets, I'd definitely go to Astronomy SE first. But craters are associated with *landing sites* and space folks pore over those *ad infinitum*, so I think questions specifically about craters and such are better asked here.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Probably "half a dozen of one & six of the other". The [International Astronomical Union](https://www.iau.org/public/themes/naming/) is the organization that names celestial features, but until the New Horizons probe flew past Pluto Earth based observations could only provide a fuzzy image of Pluto. The IAU sometimes has to rely on **Space Exploration** data to be able to name features on celestial bodies.

Answer (score 9):

[In 2020](https://nypost.com/2020/08/08/nasa-to-remove-offensive-names-from-planets-and-other-heavenly-bodies/), it was reported that NASA would no longer using "offensive" nicknames for celestial bodies.

> Under the new rules, the “Eskimo Nebula,” discovered in 1787 by William Hershel, will only be referred to as NGC 2392.
>
> The so-called “Siamese Twins Galaxy” will likewise be known only as NGC 4567 and NGC 4568.

NASA also [renamed Ultima Thule to Arrokoth](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/nasa-ultima-thule-arrokoth-name-nazi-controversy-new-horizons-a9200576.html) because of Nazi connections.

Other than that, during the early days of space exploration when photographic resolutions were poor some features were misnamed, such as the [Soviet Mountains](https://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/how-are-places-on-the-moon-named-48457/) on the far side of the Moon. They turned out to be a bright linear streak that was a ray from the Giordano Bruno Crater.

> With the flight of the Luna 3 probe in 1959, the Soviet Union was the first nation to image the far side of the Moon.  To the surprise of most, large regions of maria (so prominent on the near side) were mostly missing from the far side.  Although the first images were of very low quality, the Soviets couldn’t resist the urge to name newly discovered features for a variety of Russian heroes and place names, such as Tsiolkovsky and the Sea of Moscow.  Some new “features” were misidentified because of the low resolution – the name “Soviet Mountains” (no longer used) was given to a bright linear streak across the far side globe (a feature that turned out to be a long ray from the fresh crater Giordano Bruno and not a mountain range).

Additionally, since most celestial objects tend to have either an Arabic, Latin or Greek name, other cultures have been recognized by the International Astronomical Union. Some [86 new names](https://www.iau.org/news/pressreleases/detail/iau1707/) have been adopted, taken from [Australian Aboriginal](https://www.australiangeographic.com.au/topics/science-environment/2018/01/stars-renamed-in-recognition-of-aboriginal-astronomy/), Chinese, Coptic, Hindu, Mayan, Polynesian, and South African cultures.

---

Edit 20-June 2021

In [2002](https://lunasociety.org/eppinger-lunar-crater), The International Astronomy Union unanimously voted to drop the designation of crater Eppinger from the Moon.

> An inquiry opened with the International Astronomical Union (IAU) and the U.S. Geological Survey’s Planetary Nomenclature section regarding the suitability of having a crater on the Moon named to honor Dr. Hans Eppinger, Jr., an accused Nazi war criminal, has resulted in the removal of the designation.
>
> Upon the removal of the Eppinger designation, the IAU’s Working Group for Planetary System Nomenclature reinstated the crater’s original listing as Euclides D

On some [older maps of the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4stner_(crater)), Craters,

> Kästner B, R, and S are called Defoe, Shekhov, and Cellini on some older maps, but these names were not approved by the IAU.

[In 2020](https://www.fudzilla.com/news/51103-scientists-discover-nazi-monuments-on-the-dark-side-of-the-moon), it was reported the IAU has also recommended that the [Lenard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenard_(crater)) and [Stark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_(crater)) craters on the far side of the Moon should be quickly renamed. The two craters are named after Nazi scientists. The pair were largely responsible for the idea that there was an “Aryan physics”. They also actively embraced Nazi policies during the 1930s.

Comment: It seems that [von Braun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wernher_von_Braun#Involvement_with_the_Nazi_regime) got [a pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Braun_(crater)) in this case.

Comment: Anything can still happen in the fullness of time, but I think his involvement with the successful US space program which occurred after his "activities in Germany" prior to 1946 might just "redeem" him. He is now a US hero, albeit a [flawed one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frAEmhqdLFs).

Comment: While researching this topic I was struck by the number of lunar craters named after [Jesuit scientists](https://www.americamagazine.org/politics-society/2019/07/12/why-are-so-many-craters-moon-named-after-jesuits), dating  back to the 16th Century. There are [35 now](http://www.faculty.fairfield.edu/jmac/sj/scientists/lunacrat.htm), about 5 were renamed. Some [asteroids & comets](https://aleteia.org/2019/07/19/jesuits-on-the-moon-why-so-many-craters-are-named-for-them/) have also been named after them.

Comment: Thank you for turning me on to Tom Lehrer! I'll be enjoying those videos muchly now. And being the stack-addict I am, I had to ask [What is/was “uraneous oxide”? Was it an accepted name for a compound or mixed oxides of uranium?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/153160/16035)

Comment: had you meant to link to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjDEsGZLbio) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEJ9HrZq7Ro) or perhaps [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEJ9HrZq7Ro) instead?

Comment: and previously you thought the internet was full cats? There are Tom Lehrer videos waiting to pounce on the unsuspecting, as well.  Oh no! What have started. :-)

Comment: One of the prescient things about the von Braun video, despite being recorded in the mid 1960s, is the ended "... in German & English I know how to count down, **but I'm learning Chinese** ..."